# How does Ordering.by(_.toLowerCase) work for a case insensitive lookup in a TreeMap in Scala?

Tags: scala, treemap

So, I had to implement a case insensitive look up for a Map and I used a TreeMap to achieve this:

```
val treeMap = TreeMap(someOtherMap.toArray: _*)(Ordering.by(_.toLowerCase))
```

and `treeMap.get("FOo")` and `treeMap.get("foo")` return the same results as expected. My question is, how does the `(Ordering.by(_.toLowerCase))` additional parameter help in the `get()`? I'm looking at the [source code here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/TreeMap.scala#L125) and it goes `RB.get(key)`.

How does the additional `Ordering.by()` exactly help in case-insensitive lookups? Does it take the lookup `key`, convert to lowercase, and look up keys in the `Map` in lowercase and then match and return the value? (Extremely naive explanation, I know but I can't seem to reason how otherwise)

New to Scala and hence trying to understand the internal workings here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you dig a bit more into `RB.get(key)`, which is an implementation of a [Red-black Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) data structure, you'll see the following code in method `scala.collection.immutable.RedBlackTree#lookup`

```scala
  @tailrec
  def lookup[A, B](tree: Tree[A, B], x: A)(implicit ordering: Ordering[A]): Tree[A, B] = if (tree eq null) null else {
    val cmp = ordering.compare(x, tree.key)
    if (cmp < 0) lookup(tree.left, x)
    else if (cmp > 0) lookup(tree.right, x)
    else tree
  }
```

It uses `ordering` to see if key `tree.key` is more or less than provided `x` key. In your case, the `ordering.compare` will return `0` when comparing `foo` and `FOo` because of `_.toLowerCase` and this will match the current node in the tree and the last `else tree` returns the value associated with key `foo`.